# Non framework implementation of a hierarchical drop down for Firefox

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, hierarchical-data, html-select

I need a hierarchical drop down `<select><option/></select>` for use within a browser, preferably Firefox.  I'd rather not use a framework like jQuery.  Please spare me the questions as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I need... http://www.leigeber.com/2008/11/drop-down-menu/.

Answer (score 0):

Found this... http://spicebrains.com/multi-level-drop-down-menu/